# What's the default value of int fields of a local struct variable?

Tags: c

What's the default value of int fields of a local struct variable?  Will they be zeroed automatically? Or, will they be the same as any other local variables, filled with garbage values?

Comment: C will not do things you don't ask it to. That would make it inefficient. Zeroing memory would translate to additional instructions...

Comment: Ok, but I want to make sure if it zeroes local structures. I mean, even if I don't ask it to zero every field of the structure, does it zero them in this special case??

Comment: Can't you test this yourself in just a few minutes? Declare a structure, a variable for it, don't initialize it, and print out the structure members. Are they all zeros? Whatever happened to trying to figure out things yourself before running off to ask someone else?

Comment: For sure I can test it by myself, but I just want to re-confirm that! XD

Comment: @KenWhite - That result would not answer the question in general. If the members are all zero, is that due to the compiler, the OS, or the standard? Given that globals / static variables have different semantics, it's a reasonable question.

Comment: @BrettHale: It would be a reasonable question if the poster had shown any effort at all (sample code, some links to documentation they found unclear, etc.).

Answer (score 10):

If the variable has automatic storage — a local variable — and is not explicitly initialized, its state is indefinite.  That applies regardless of whether it is a simple variable (e.g. an `int`) or complex (e.g. a structure or union).

The fields will not reliably be zeroed.

[C11 §6.7.9 Initialization ¶10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10):

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `static` variables are automatically initialized to zero, including local static variables.

Consider this example:

```
typedef struct
{
    int alpha;
    char bravo;
    float charlie;
}  ThreeVarStruct_T;        // Define a structure

int function(void)  // Local Scope
{
    ThreeVarStruct_T        exampleA; // This will hold uninitialized "random" data
    static ThreeVarStruct_T exampleB; // This is guaranteed to be initialized to zero
}
```